# IOS App Validating Error: An SSL error has occurred and secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl, app-store

In XCode, I tried to upload a new version of an app A, but it gives this error EVERYTIME. Then I had another app B to be uploaded, it goes ok (validate ok, and upload ok). Then I return to the app A, it still give the same error.

I tried: 1. Restart XCode. 2. Restart Mac. 3. Clean All and Re-Archive.

Still the same error. What gives? [image]

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: hi raj.. did you solve this.

Comment: Same issue here... any solution?

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In Keychain Access application, select system (under keychains) and keys (under Category) and delete the localhost keys.

Comment: Hi michael m.c how to find the localhost keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running iOS 9+, try adding this value to your plist:

[image]